# Convert dataframe to a matrix with counts

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, dplyr

I have an R data frame in R which looks like this:

```
 data.frame(ID = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2","2","2","3","3","3","3"),  
    plist = c("CP1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P1", "P2","P3","CP2","CP1","P2","P3","P5"))
```

Now, I want to create a matrix with counts based on the values present in plist as below:

|  | P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 | P5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CP1 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| CP2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

This means CP1 is present along with P2 in 2 samples, with P3 in 2 samples but with P5 in only 1 sample.

Any ideas how can I do this?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the comment. But that does not seem to give me the matrix I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with base R.
First, let's assume that the data-frame is called `dat`:

```
dat <-  data.frame(ID = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2","2","2","3","3","3","3"),  
plist = c("CP1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P1", "P2","P3","CP2","CP1","P2","P3","P5"))
```

Then create the "empty" count matrix

```
plist <- dat$plist
rowvec <- sort(unique(grep("^CP[0-9]+$", plist, value = TRUE)))
colvec <- sort(unique(grep("^P[0-9]+$", plist, value = TRUE)))
count.mat <- matrix(0, length(rowvec), length(colvec), dimnames = list(rowvec, colvec))
```

Then loop on the IDs:

```
for (id in unique(dat$ID)) {
  rowids <- grep("^CP[0-9]+$", dat$plist[dat$ID == id], value = TRUE)
  colids <- grep("^P[0-9]+$", dat$plist[dat$ID == id], value = TRUE)
  count.mat[rowids, colids] <- count.mat[rowids, colids] + 1
}
```

You might want to add some tests to make sure that there are no duplicate "CPi" or "Pi" per ID.

Here is what the result looks like

```
    P1 P2 P3 P4 P5
CP1  0  2  2  1  1
CP2  1  1  1  0  0
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution @Vincent. I would like to accept your solution as an answer because with minimal edits I could apply your solution to my original data to get required results.

Answer (score 2):

Your data is very badly structured. Here is an idea though,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
 arrange(ID, plist) %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 mutate(new = first(plist)) %>% 
 slice(-1L) %>% 
 arrange(plist)%>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = plist, values_from = ID, values_fn = length, values_fill = 0) %>% 
 arrange(new)

# A tibble: 2 × 6
  new      P1    P2    P3    P4    P5
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 CP1       0     2     2     1     1
2 CP2       1     1     1     0     0
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Sotos. I have used Vincent solution for my requirements this time.